# To add a new row after the first row in CSV file

Tags: csv, vbscript

I have a CSV file with the contents as below:

```
"week","Country"
201504,"IN"
201505,"JP"
```

I need to add a new row after the first row (i.e., after `"week","Country"`) and also I need to add `12345678,"AB"` as the content to this new row. I tried splitting into arrays and used vbnewline as shown in the below code but it didn't work. Can anybody please help me out on this:

```
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objInFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\I_Calls.csv", 1, true, 0)
strContents = objInFile.ReadAll
objInFile.Close
Dim arrRows
arrRows = split(strContents, vbNewLine)
arrRows = arrRows(0) & vbNewLine
strContents = join(arrRows, vbNewLine)
set objOutFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\I_Calls.csv", 2, true, 0)
objOutFile.WriteLine strContents
objOutFile.close
```

Answer (score 2):

```
set objOutFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\I_Calls.csv", 2, true, 0)
'First write the header row
objOutFile.WriteLine arrRows(0)
'Write the extra line.
objOutFile.WriteLine "12345678,""AB"""
'Write the existing content skipping the first header row.
for i=1 to UBound(arrRows)
    objOutFile.WriteLine arrRows(i)
next
objOutFile.close
```

Comment: Actually writing the data and quoting the AB really helps; but Split() could be used more intellegently.

Comment: Hi. I declared array and later integrated this code and it worked fine. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

A .CSV is a database table and there is no 'natural' order in a relation. So to insist on putting data in a specific row is like saying that `3+4` is different from `4+3` - it shows a lack of understanding. So @brettdj's answer is the correct one (if you add one EOL and quote the AB).

Assuming that "writing to the second row" is the bad idea of a stupid boss or customer, the poor programmer should follow one of these sets of general rules:

Set A for an experienced person:

1. Make a decent plan based on your experience
2. Implement it

Set B for a less experienced person:

1. Get some sample code from the internet and adapt it to your problem
2. Test it and note down the manifest problems
3. Add "Option Explicit"
4. Look up all functions/subs/methods used and make sure you understand their full feature sets
5. Avoid repetitions by using Consts, variables, and functions/subs/methods
6. Delete every (cargo cult/error prone/repetitive) fat from your first version

Both ways will give you

```
Option Explicit

Const csFSpec = "..\data\35976978.csv"
Dim csEOL : csEOL = vbCrLf

Function qq(s)
  qq = """" & s & """"
End Function

Dim oFS : Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oTS : Set oTS = oFS.OpenTextFile(csFSpec)
Dim aRows : aRows = split(oTS.ReadAll(), csEOL, 2)
oTS.Close
Set oTS = oFS.CreateTextFile(csFSpec)
oTS.Write Join(Array(aRows(0), Join(Array(12345678, qq("AB")), ","), aRows(1)), csEOL)
oTS.Close
```

output:

```
type ..\data\35976978.csv
"week","Country"
201504,"IN"
201505,"JP"

cscript 35976978.vbs

type ..\data\35976978.csv
"week","Country"
12345678,"AB"
201504,"IN"
201505,"JP"
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. It really made me to work on this more.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the file in `Append` mode

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objinFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\I_lls.csv", 8, True)
objinFile.Write "12345678,AB"
objinFile.Close
```

Comment: Hi. The above code will add that row at the end of the table. But it won't add as the second row  as mentioned in the query. Can you help on how to add this as the second row of the table ?

Comment: Correct solution in general; AB needs quotes; one extra EOL needed.

Comment: Only code was added, the question (how to insert a new record after the header line) remained unchanged.

Comment: Yes. Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers no, the initial data from the csv file all presented in a single line, an edit was made to present it in 3 lines.

Comment: The edit that formatted the CSV sample correctly was made by me, 3 hours before you posted your answer. Please check the revision history. I'm not making this up.